# Lock element on the right

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two textboxes in my app, with a variable lenght. One is on the left, the other one on the right. By default their width is pretty little, 30 px. But as they contain a lot of numbers, the textbox on the left shifts the right one and enlarges the window (same thing when the right textbw contains too many numbers). To avoid this, I would like to stabilize the right textbox on the right, even if its width rises.

I've tried to play with the columns size, but not.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                                    
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="maxGmapWest" Text="{Binding Path=Options.MaxGmapWest, ElementName=Window, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}" PreviewTextInput="Tab1_PreviewTextInput" Width="auto" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" MinWidth="30" Margin="230,0,0,0" Name="maxGmapEast" Text="{Binding Path=Options.MaxGmapEast, ElementName=Window, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}" PreviewTextInput="Tab1_PreviewTextInput" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, why 4 columns for only two objects? Also, if you want the one on the right to stay a fixed width, why not set it with the fixed width and set your first column be width="*"? Maybe a quick image of what you're after would describe your requirements a little better?

Comment: sounds to me like you just need to set a max width on both of your Text Boxes

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that markup

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Width="auto" MinWidth="50" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxHeight="40" >
            <TextBox  Name="maxGmapWest"  TextWrapping="Wrap"   />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  MinWidth="50"  Margin="0,0,20,0" MaxHeight="40">
            <TextBox   Name="maxGmapEast"  TextWrapping="Wrap"   />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

maxwidth for textbox=width of column, fixed max height and using ScrollViewer for large text